# Accordion with jQuery (not jQueryUI) - there's a "DRY" way to do this.. just don't know how

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Basically I want to add the class "active" to whatever (+) I click, along with changing the pseudo content from "+" to "-", then back to "+" when the "active" class is removed. I originally used the jQueryUI accordion method, but the animation wasn't completely fluid so I'm trying this route.

```
one = $('.first');
two = $('.second')
three =$('.third')

$('.one').click(function() {
    one.toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
});

$('.two').click(function() {
    two.toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
});

$('.three').click(function() {
    three.toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

Everything is fully functional in my [codepen](http://codepen.io/johndurso/pen/rjdgZP), just trying to get better at DRY jQuery.

Comment: As you say, your code is fully-functional in your codepen. Exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just asking if there's a simpler way to code this so it has the same type of functionality with less lines of code. @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to target the shared classes. In your case, add a single `click` event listener to the `.more` elements and then when the element is clicked, toggle the `.show` class while selecting the previous `.dropdown` element and toggling the `.active` class.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgjEEX)

Here is a simplified snippet:

```
$('.more').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('show').prev('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could also traverse the DOM and select the closest `.price` ancestor element and then select the descendant `.price` element and toggle the corresponding classes.

The advantage to this approach is that the code will continue to work even if the order of the elements is changed or if the nesting differs. In other words, it is more flexible and is less likely to break with future changes.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgjXKz)

```
$('.more').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('show')
           .closest('.price').find('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I like the DOM option more! It's more straight forward. Thanks so much @Josh Crozier.